# How can i add spinner to the toolbar in the particular fragment.Can anyone tell me how can i do this?

Tags: android, spinner, toolbar

This is my `onActivityCreated()` method:

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

This is my `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method when i inflate the spinner and set the adapter:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_spinner);
        mCountrySpinner = (Spinner) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);

        ArrayAdapter<String> countryAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, mCountryList);
                countryAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        mCountrySpinner.setAdapter(countryAdapter);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
     }
```

This is my menu xml where i added the item and set `app:actionViewClass` as `android.widget.Spinner`:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">
```

This is the item i inflated in the menu xml:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_spinner"
    android:background="#ff00"
    android:title="@string/countryname"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"
    app:showAsAction="always"></item>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `onCreateView()` of your fragment 
call this `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` and then inflate your menu in your fragment

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.fragment_menu, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.spinner);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.spinner_list_item_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    return true;
}
```

do create a menu xml with name `fragment_menu` and set `spinner` as `actionView` in `menuItem`.

Comment: sir.i am using same procedure. see my code. but it does not work .

Comment: can you post your menu xml and try setting setHasOptionsMenu(true) in onCreateView()

Comment: sir,please check my menu xml.

Comment: just remove the context part from menu

Comment: sir,the spinner it showing in the toolbar.but when i select the item it does not displaying in the toolbar.

Comment: sir,i got my problem. problem is that when i getting the data from the server it does not dispalying.but when i set it dynamically.its works fine.can you help me.if you know anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

create fragment_menu.xml in menu and add following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:title="ActionBar Spinner"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.Spinner"
        android:background="#ff00"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Override onCreateOptionsMenu method of fragment and add folloing code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.fragment_menu, menu);

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.spinner);
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.spinner_list_item_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        return true;
}
```

hope this may work.

Comment: this works in activity. but i want to add spinner in fragment.and same code i also using. but it does not work.

Comment: @aman You can use menu.findItem(R.id.spinner).setVisible(false); in activity onCreateOptionMenu method and in fragment set to true.

Comment: its working. but when i select the item it does not displaying in the toolbar.

Comment: Please check this link:http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2015/10/android-spinner-in-toolbar.html